# Set onClickListener to button in bottom sheet layout

Tags: java, android, bottom-sheet

I want to add onClickListener to a button in the bottom sheet layout dialog. But it is not working. Nothing happens when i click on the button.

CODE

```
    button_right = layoutBottomSheet.findViewById(R.id.button_cod);
    button_wrong = layoutBottomSheet.findViewById(R.id.button_paytm);
    layoutBottomSheet = findViewById(R.id.bottom_sheet_layout);
    sheetBehavior = BottomSheetBehavior.from(layoutBottomSheet);



     confirmButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            if (sheetBehavior.getState() != BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED) {
                sheetBehavior.setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED);
            } else {
                sheetBehavior.setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_COLLAPSED);
            }

        }

    });

    button_right.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(CartActivity.this, "Right", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

    button_wrong.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(CartActivity.this, "Wrong", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
```

Comment: Post the code for dialog setup. May be you didn't bind the *button* by id.

Comment: Check it, I am following this tutorial https://www.androidhive.info/2017/12/android-working-with-bottom-sheet/

Answer (score 3):

You need to bind the `button` by `id`.

Like

```
Button confirmButton = (Button) layoutBottomSheet.findViewById(R.id.confirmButton);

Button button_right = (Button) layoutBottomSheet.findViewById(R.id.button);
```

Likewise And then you can go with click.

Comment: confirm button is working, button_right and button_wrong is not working.

Comment: @user9658973 Yes go the same way for *button_right* check updated answer.

Comment: @user9658973 Make sure you pass the correct id of button  which you defined in *XML layout*  i just put the reference for answer.

Comment: @user9658973 You are still doing wrong man !! *button_wrong = layoutBottomSheet.findViewById(R.id.button_paytm);* this is wrong. Do like this *button_wrong = (Button) layoutBottomSheet.findViewById(R.id.button_paytm);*.

Comment: yes, but on click for button is not working, if i put textview and set click listener then it works

Answer (score 0):

If you are following [beehive tutorial](https://www.androidhive.info/2017/12/android-working-with-bottom-sheet/), then you just need to inflate that layout and then call button through that view.

```
View view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.fragment_filters, null);
                BottomSheetDialog dialog = new BottomSheetDialog(getActivity());
                dialog.setContentView(view);
                dialog.show();
                final Button button = view.findViewById(R.id.helloworld);
                button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "ok", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                });
```

Notice

> final Button button = view.findViewById(R.id.helloworld);

where view equals

> View view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.fragment_filters,
>   null);

i.e. the fragment i'm using to display in bottom sheet. Hope this helps